# Running inside Guice injector, @Injects not respected on `new`-ed class

Tags: java, debugging, guice

We have a Swing-application we would like to add a slight touch of dependency injection to using Guice-3.0.  Our reason is to migrate our old Factories into something more flexible.

I have ensured that the application runs inside an injector, and we now want to have a class way down have some fields @Inject'ed, and it *appears* to my untrained eye that the @Inject annotations on this class is ignored when the "new" is running.

Question now is if I have understood correctly that classes being new'ed when first running inside a Guice injector are guaranteed to have their @Inject annotations respected, or if this property is lost after one or more new's in your code.

In other words:

**Given A gets an instance of B from Guice, and B then creates `new C()` which in turn runs `new D()`, and D happen to have @Inject's inside, should D be processed by Guice?**

If yes, how can I add code to my Guice configuration that allows me to see that "new X()" is being processed by Guice and that "@Inject setY(Y y)" is being executed?  I do not mind if this log will be very large - I just need to verify that Guice is working as I expect it to.

Comment: How do you 'get and instance of B from Guice' ? Using injector.getInstance ? If you create C and D by using new, after the creation of B, then I guess Guice's injector never creates anything. Don't you want to make C an injected dependency of B, and D an injected dependency of C ?

Comment: @phtrivier, yes, using injector.getInstance.  We do not want to change B and C for now as it is a non-trivial application and we just want this tiny corner working.

Answer (score 7):

No, *nothing* created with `new` directly is handled by Guice... it doesn't do magic. The way Guice is supposed to work is that it creates your object graphs for you. You aren't supposed to reference the `Injector` within your classes and you aren't supposed to use `new` to create services that you want injected.

Here are some options you might have:

- Inject `C` into `B` rather than `new`ing it. Inject `D` into `C`.
- If you need to create either or both of these multiple times within the class you're currently `new`ing them in, inject `Provider<C>` or `Provider<D>` instead and use `get()` rather than `new`.
- If there are objects only available at runtime that need to be passed to these classes (something based on user input or data from elsewhere, say) to create them, you may need to use Assisted Inject and inject a `CFactory` or `DFactory` instead of a `Provider`.
- If you really can't find any better way, you can use `injector.injectMembers(Object)` to inject objects you've created with `new`... but it's hard to say if Guice is helping you much if you're doing that.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Hm, I glanced through the Weld user's guide and didn't see anything that made it sound like it does that, but who knows. I don't think there's any way to inject `new`ed objects without some kind of aspect weaving, and even then I think it's a bad idea. Constructor injection is greatly preferable to fields or methods, and that certainly isn't possible at all if you use `new`.

Answer (score 4):

As ColinD pointed out, in your example D would not be created by Guice. Calling new on an Object will construct it outside of a the Guice DI. If you want to confirm that something is being created through Guice, you could add logging to the @Inject setter methods or if you're doing constructor injection, you could add a new method just for logging purposes:

```
@Inject
public void log() {
    logger.debug(//check if injected classes have been set)
    ...
}
```

Having converted a large, Swing application to use Guice, and written a new one from the ground up there are some things to keep in mind.

1) Guice was not designed for desktop applications. It was created for use on Servers. Startup time is not something that was taken into consideration. After fully converting a Swing application from all static factories to all Guice, it added ~30/60 seconds onto the startup time depending on if it was a cold or warm startup.

2) It's very difficult to add only some Guice. As you're now discovering you'll quickly want a dependency on a constructed class three levels deep and either have to convert it all to Guice or start passing lots of classes through constructors and add getters

3) Beware of eagerly creating objects with Guice. @Singleton by default eagerly constructs the object at startup. This can be disastrous to startup time of the app. If you're worried about this there's a nice thread on the Guice forum about creating a @EagerSingleton or @LazySingleton to might want to check out

4) with all that being said, Guice is pretty awesome, just have to be aware of how its working to get good performance with it in a desktop app

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I'd much rather that _Guice_ told me what it was doing instead of my code notifying me of the fact.  Do you know how to do that?