# Guice: Do I have to annotate every class of an object graph with @Inject?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'd like to **introduce Guice** for the use of an existing mid-sized project.
For my demands I need a custom scope (session is too big, while request to small for my project).

Imagine that I **request** guice to provide me **an instance of Class A** which has direct and indirect dependencies to **many other classes** (composition).

My custom provider is able to provide the instance of classes which are used as constructor arguments of all involved classes.

**Question:**

- Do I really have to put an `@Inject` (and my custom scope) annotation on the constructors of all involved classes or **is there a way** that guice **only requires** these annotations on the **top-level class** which I request and that all further dependencies are resolved by "asking" my custom scope for a provider of the dependent types?

If this is true this would increase the effort of introducing Guice because I have to adjust more than 1000 classes. Any help and experiences during the introduction of guice is appreciated.

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123782/running-inside-guice-injector-injects-not-respected-on-new-ed-class interesting

Comment: Note that `@Inject` is also a [JSR 330 annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JSR330), so using it does not itself couple your code to Guice.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, it's possible to use Guice without putting an `@Inject` annotation anywhere. Guice supports [Provider bindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings), [@Provides methods](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) and [constructor bindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings), all of which allow you to bind types however you choose. However, for its normal operation it requires `@Inject` annotations to serve as metadata telling it what dependencies a class requires and where it can inject them.

There reason for this is that otherwise, it cannot deterministically tell what it should inject and where. For example, classes may have multiple constructors and Guice needs some way of choosing one to inject that doesn't rely on any guessing. You could say "well, my classes only have one constructor so it shouldn't need `@Inject` on that", but what happens when someone adds a new constructor to a class? Then Guice no longer has its basis for deciding and the application breaks. Additionally, this all assumes that you're only doing constructor injection. While constructor injection is certainly the best choice in general, Guice allows injection of methods (and fields) as well, and the problem of needing to specify the injection points of a class explicitly is stronger there since most classes will have many methods that are not used for injection and at most a few that are.

In addition to `@Inject`'s importance in telling Guice, it also serves as documentation of how a class is intended to be used--that the class is part of an application's dependency injection wired infrastructure. It also helps to be *consistent* in applying `@Inject` annotations across your classes, even if it wouldn't currently be absolutely necessary on some that just use a single constructor. I'd also note that you can use [JSR-330's](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JSR330) `@javax.inject.Inject` annotation in Guice 3.0 if a standard Java annotation is preferable to a Guice-specific one to you.

I'm not too clear on what you mean by asking the scope for a provider. Scopes generally do not create objects themselves; they control when to ask the unscoped provider of a dependency for a new instance and how to control the scope of that instance. Providers are part of how they operate, of course, but I'm not sure if that's what you mean. If you have some custom way of providing instances of objects, `Provider` bindings and `@Provides` methods are the way to go for that and don't require `@Inject` annotations on the classes themselves.

Comment: Comprehensive answer, thank you. Additional question: What about 3rd party classes/interfaces (e.g. javax.persistence.EntityManager) - all three methods you described seem to be scopeless - what if such a 3rd party class needs to be retrieved within a (custom) scope? I know how to retrieve the correct instance but unfortunately the scope() method is never called for classes without an @Inject. (this is what I meant with "asking" my custom scope)

Comment: Nice answer. Most people tend to think that Guice, because it's annotation based, is an invasive DI framework, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: What if you want to move away from Guice to another DI provider, you are left with @inject() all over

Comment: @skjagini `@Inject` is now a standard Java annotation (`javax.inject.Inject`) that works with most Java DI frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

NO YOU DONT

GUICE does not ask you to inject every single object. GUICE will try and create only injected objects. So you can @Inject objects that you want to be injected.

On the scope bit - Scope essentially controls how your objects gets created by GUICE. When you write your own custom scope you can have a datastructure that controls the way objects are created. When you scope a class with your custom annotation, GUICE will call your scope method before creation with a Provider for that class. You can then decide if you want to create a new object or use an existing object from a datastructure (such as hashmap or something). If you want to use an existing one you get that and return the object, else you do a provider.get() and return.

Notice this

```
public <T> Provider<T> scope(final Key<T> key, final Provider<T> unscoped) {
    return new Provider<T>() {
      public T get() {
        Map<Key<?>, Object> scopedObjects = getScopedObjectMap(key);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T current = (T) scopedObjects.get(key);
        if (current == null && !scopedObjects.containsKey(key)) {
          current = unscoped.get();
          scopedObjects.put(key, current);
        }
        // what you return here is going to be injected ....
        // in this scope object you can have a datastructure that holds all references 
        // and choose to return that instead depending on your logic and external 
        // dependencies such as session variable etc...
        return current;
      }
    };
  }
```

Here's a tutorial ...

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the question was if I have to put the @Inject annotation on every class in the object graph. I am not asking about instantiating all these classes.

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level, the `@Inject` annotation identifies the stuff guice will need to set for you.  You can have guice inject into a field directly, into a method, or into a constructor.  You must use the `@Inject` annotation every time you want guice to inject an object.

[Here](http://www.factorypattern.com/google-guice-tutorial/) is a guice tutorial.

Comment: So in other words your answer of my question is "yes, i have to adjust all classes with both annotations of an object graph"? From my perspective, this is an unnecessary requirement and increases "annotation pollution" and cost for the introduction of guice.

Comment: If you are using a tool, you must use the tool.  You only need to use guice to inject those objects that you wish to inject.  You must; however, use the @Inject to inject any and all objects that you wish to inject. You do not pick up a hammer and say "dammit, why do I need to hit the darn nails, why can't the hammer magically do that for me?"  The same applys to guice.

Comment: That's true but I can imagine that guice could be intelligent enough to work like the following: 1. verify @Inject and get scope from requested top level class 2. if there are further dependencies to check for an ``@Inject`` OR to ask the desired scope of the top level class for a provider of this dependency. This could be implemented easily in guice and would greatly reduce the introduction effort.